# How do I get the value of a datepicker ? Is there a changed-event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hi I have a big problem with the Date-, Timepicker.
I need to use it in a form which gets submitted in the background via AJAX the problem is that the value is always null (empty string). I guess the Picker sets the value when the form is submitted but in this case it doesn't really submits.

1) How do I get the value ?

2) Is there any changed-event ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) How do I get the value ?

There's the [`getDate` method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-getDate). Or, of course, read the value of the underlying `input`.

> 2) Is there any changed-event ?

Yes, there's the [`onSelect` event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect).

It may be worth (re)reviewing [the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)...

---

Surprisingly, the deep links above don't quite seem to work. For `getDate`, go to [the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) and click "Methods", then "getDate". For `onSelect`, go to [the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) and click "Options", then "onSelect".